# How can I select the rest of the row with DISTINCT?

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I have a table where I keep messages and one where I keep users.
I want to get all the users that interactioned (send or received a message) with user_id 1.
This query works:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a2f3/1

EDIT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    (CASE WHEN `user_to_id` = 1 THEN `user_from_id` ELSE `user_to_id` END) `user_id`,
    users.*
FROM `messages`
INNER JOIN users 
ON (CASE WHEN `user_to_id` = 1 THEN `user_from_id` ELSE `user_to_id` END) = users.user_id
WHERE `user_to_id` = 1 OR `user_from_id` = 1
ORDER BY `time` DESC
```

But if I add to SELECT the `message` column, it returns duplicate records:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a2f3/2

EDIT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  (CASE WHEN `user_to_id` = 1 THEN `user_from_id` ELSE `user_to_id` END) `user_id`,
  `messages`.`message`,
  users.*
FROM `messages`
INNER JOIN users 
ON (CASE WHEN `user_to_id` = 1 THEN `user_from_id` ELSE `user_to_id` END) = users.user_id
WHERE `user_to_id` = 1 OR `user_from_id` = 1
ORDER BY `time` DESC
```

How can I fix that?

And also, I see that it orders the results after the "DISTINCT" selection was made. The first query should return the results inverted because the row with `message_id` 2 has `time` 3.
Is there a way I can order them before the "DISTINCT"?

EDIT 2: I wasn't clear about the question. I want to select only the last message for a matched user_id.

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question. It should be self-containing.

Comment: it's not a duplicate since it's a different `message`.

Comment: @juergend The code is on sqlfiddle with the schema built.

Comment: @Lamak Yea, but I want to select the last message and only the `user_id` distinct.

Comment: Yes, but if SQLFiddle is down the question is useless. And we try to build a knowledge base being useful to **future** visitors.

Comment: @AlexSorinDachin Fair enough, but that requirement isn't on your question, we can't just guess what it is that you want

Comment: @Lamak Sorry, my fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
    users.*,
    (SELECT `message` from messages 
     WHERE 
    (CASE WHEN `user_to_id` = 1 THEN `user_from_id` ELSE `user_to_id` END) = users.user_id
     AND (`user_to_id` = 1 OR `user_from_id` = 1)
     ORDER BY `time` DESC limit 1
     ) AS message
  FROM users
) a 
WHERE message IS NOT NULL
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a2f3/26)

Comment: No, that query shows all the users. I want to return the rows just like the first query, but appended with the last message. Just like facebook returns all the participants you had a conversation with in message center (with the last message received or sent).

Comment: @AlexSorinDachin, query updated with only show users with messages

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I wanted :)

Comment: I've change it so it orders the final results by time: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92426/3

Answer (score 0):

It's not returning duplicate records, you have two records with User_ID = 2.

I'm confused by what you want them to be ordered by. If you want to order them in the inverted order, just remove 'DESC'

Comment: I don't want two records for the same user_id matched. I want only the last message. Like facebook messages center retrieves all the users who interactioned with you.